# python; create file on remote server with variable file name

Tags: python

Using the paramiko library in python im trying to touch a file on remote location and able to do so using below code..

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=servername,username=usr,password=pass)
cmd = "touch /home/test/file.txt"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
stdout = stdout.readlines()
stderr = stderr.readlines()
```

however, as next step the file im trying to create on remote having name depends on a variable.. so it should be like

```
cmd = "touch /home/test/var_file.txt"
```

where var could be anything a variable..
i have tried server options to create that file but not working..
can anyone guide on how to achieve it..

Comment: Are you familiar with [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) in Python?  `cmd = f'touch /home/test/{filename}'`

Comment: String concatenation also working in python `cmd = 'touch /home/test/' + var +  '_file.txt'`. And third way: `cmd = "touch /home/test/%s_file.txt" % var`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import os
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=servername,username=usr,password=pass)

name_of_file = "Test.txt"

path_to_file = os.path.join('/home/test/', name_of_file)

cmd = f"touch {path_to_file}"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
stdout = stdout.readlines()
stderr = stderr.readlines()
```